# How can I format my code on mac automatically?

Tags: html, format

I am using Text Wrangler on my Mac. After a while of coding my code is a little bit out of format. So I was looking for a button, that will format my code properly. Exactly like this online tool: http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Do you know a good code editor for mac that has this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shall consider switching to modern code editors like:

**[atom](https://atom.io/) or [brackets](http://brackets.io/) and can make use of plugins for formatting code like [atom beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) and [brackets beautify](https://github.com/brackets-beautify/brackets-beautify) respectively.**

Answer (score 2):

http://brackets.io is one of my favorites, it has all of the formatting out of the box, you can also do W3C validation with an extension.